# Generate Microsoft GUID without network card

Tags: sql-server, guid

Have a look at the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215.aspx

As per the above link, `NEWID()` will consist of the Identification number of the Network card but what will happen if a machine does not have a Network card?

Will this `NEWID()` still generate a number?

Comment: Have you tried disabling your network card and calling NEWID()?

Answer (score 2):

Only the old V1 GUIDs used the network card's ID, until it was exploited by a particularly nasty virus and Microsoft decided to move the concept along to a more modern idea.

Windows now uses a specially designed pseudo-random number generator. See the following URLs for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_.28MAC_address.29